# Add image to accordion header and keep accordion open on page load

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng, angular9

I am using primeng accordion. My code is as follows:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
       Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

example link with stackblitz:

https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion

I want to add an image to the accordion header. The location of image should be between accordion arrow and accordion heading. Also I want to keep first accoridion open when page loads. If there is no content in first accordion, then by default second accordion should be opened. How can I do that?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Inside each of your `<p-accordionTab>` elements you can specify the header template or the content template. It is documented in the primeNG documentation.

Check the following on your code:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab [selected]="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <img [src]="imgSrc">
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="content">Content 1</ng-template>
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Comment: how can  I keep accordion open by default when page loads?

Comment: See my update. You still use the `selected` attr to make it as selected.

Comment: Again, I am not a pro with primeNG, and the stackblitz site doesn't seem to be working tonight.

Comment: selected is working fine but image thing is not working